# Java - Compare two Maps entries for specific keys only

Tags: java, dictionary, compare, equals

Suppose I have two maps:

```
    Map<String, String> map1 = Map.of(
        "a", "1",
        "b", "2",
        "c", "3",
        "x", "9"
    );
    Map<String, String> map2 = Map.of(
        "z", "9"
        "a", "1",
        "b", "2",
        "c", "3"
    );
```

Now I want to compare these maps for only the following keys, to see if they contain the same values: ["a", "b", "c"]

One straightforward approach can be:

```
public boolean customEquals(Map map1, Map map2){ //please ignore NullPointerException
    return map1.get("a").equals(map2.equals("a"))
            && map1.get("b").equals(map2.equals("b"))
            && map1.get("c").equals(map2.equals("c"));
}
```

But this is very inefficient and smelly to code if there are many more keys to check. In that case a better approach can be:

```
public boolean customEquals(Map map1, Map map2) { //please ignore NullPointerException
    Set<String> keys = Set.of("a", "b", "c");
    for (String key : keys) {
        if (!(map1.get(key).equals(map2.get(key)))) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Is there any better way to do this? (You can recommend popular library functions as well)

Comment: `if (map1.get(key).equals(map2.equals(key))) {
            return false;
        }` edit: if condition should be not equals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Stream.of("a","b","c").allMatch(key -> map1.get(key).equals(map2.get(key)));
```

Comment: In the question, he said to ignore NullPointerException

Comment: I am picking this one as the accepted answer as it is the cleanest solution, without creating too much new objects and serving my purpose completely.

Answer (score 3):

First get the entries of key=[a,b,c] from `map1` or `map2` into `List`

```
List<SimpleEntry<String,String>> res = Stream.of("a","b","c")
                                   .map(key->new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String,String>(key, map1.get(key)))
                                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And then you can check all these entries are existed in another `Map`, so in this way you need not to be worry about `NullPointerException` even any of the `Map` doesn't having value for `[a,b,c]`

```
res.stream().allMatch(entry->map2.entrySet().contains(entry))  //convert map2 to entrySet before using in allMatch
```

We can also combine both of them into one line

```
Stream.of("a","b","c")
         .map(key->new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String,String>(key, map1.get(key)))
         .allMatch(entry->map2.entrySet().contains(entry));
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but this checks `.contains(entry));` where my goal is to check `equals`. Would you please edit and update?

Comment: Internally contains uses equals method for comparing string objects @TameemKhan

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding, thanks for clearing up!

Answer (score 2):

```
  private static <K, V> Map<K, V> filterEntries(Map<K, V> map, Collection<K> keys) {
    var entries = map.entrySet()
      .stream()
      .filter(entry -> keys.contains(entry.getKey()))
      .toArray(Map.Entry[]::new);
    return Map.ofEntries(entries);
  }
```

(Run above at https://repl.it/repls/StickyGaseousAutomatedinformationsystem)

Might not be a *better* way but I'd prefer to use `Stream`s to filter the map.